# What are some simple (or elegant) functions that satisfy these conditions?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

I wish to have a function that maps [0,1] to [0,1].  I also require that f(0) = 0 and f(1) = 1.

Also, I would like the function to be of sigmoidal shape, such as this:

[image]

The above function is ok, but I would like the function to be flatter at the bottom and the top, and have a steeper ascent.

Ideally I would be able to adjust the parameters of the function to control how "flat" it is.

Optional:  If I could also adjust the parameters so that I can choose where the inflection occurs that would be great.  (e.g. in the above function the inflection seems to occur at x = 0.5, but ideally I would be able to shift this to say x = 0.1, or x = 0.05 etc.)

Comment: $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2} x)$ should work.

Comment: @Crostul, that looks good - how can I adjust how "flat" it is?

Comment: $y=\int_0^x t^n(t-1)^n dt$ become flat increasing $n$, but it's not simple :)

Comment: Use www.desmos.com/calculator to plot $\sin^2({\frac{\pi}{2}x}) + 0{\sqrt{x}}^2+0{\sqrt{1-x}}^2$